# How to create and run a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers

Complete beginner at Docker and AlmaLinux here, and I'm stuck trying to set up containers in Docker. I've got Docker installed and set up (ran through the tutorials without seeming to run into any problems) on my laptop, and I'm trying to complete an assignment where the first step is to "get a AlmaLinux 8 Docker container running".

While I vaguely understand what containers are, at least in this specific context, I have no idea how to make one. Tutorials online either assume that I'm running Docker on a Linux machine or are incredibly confusing and don't actually create a container. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look for Dockerfile tutorials, they should be straightforward

Answer (score 2):

From my understandings AlmaLinux is an already existing image. So to "get a AlmaLinux 8 Docker container running" you can just:

```sh
docker run almalinux:8
```

In general containers are always run based on some image. The images are either downloaded form somewhere (as in this case the image will be downloaded from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/almalinux/almalinux)) or build locally. In the second case you would need a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command.

After the image is created then you would be able to run the container with [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)